# How to find the sum of the 2nd quartile based on a condition in R

Tags: r, optimization, mathematical-optimization

The data I have represents sales and their distance (`Dist`) to a given store `One` and `Two` in this example. What I would like to do is, to define the stores catchment area based on sales desity. A cacthment area is defined as the radius that contains 50% of sales. Starting with orders that have the smallest distance (`Dist`) to a store I would like to calculate radius that contains 50% of sales of a given store.

I the following `df` that I've calculated in a previous model.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                 Store = c('One','One','One','One','Two','Two','Two','Two'),
                 Dist = c(1,5,7,23,1,9,9,23),
                 Sales = c(10,8,4,1,11,9,4,2))
```

Now I want to find the minimum distance `dist` that gives the closes figure to 50% of `Sales`. So my output looks as follows:

```
Output <- data.frame(Store = c('One','Two'),
                 Dist = c(5,9),
                 Sales = c(18,20))
```

I have a lot of observation in my actual df and it's unlekely that I will be able to solve for exactly 50%, so I need to round to the nearest observation.

Any suggestions how to do this?

*NOTE: I appologise in advance for the poor title, I tried to think of a better way to formulate the problem, suggestions are welcome...*

Comment: I'm not completely clear on your objective, can you try to elaborate this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the algorithm which results in your expected result?

Comment: @nrussell I've provided adtional clarification on the objective. Let me know if this is more clear.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I've added adtional clarification at the begining of my question. I'm using Haversine Distance to calculate the distance of orders to a store and would now like to find the catchment area with a given sales desnity. i.e. 50% of sales are within a radius of 20K

Comment: When you say *"50% of sales"*, you mean 50% of a given store's sales, correct?

Comment: @nrussell yes that's correct.

Comment: Are there any other conditions, such as ">= 50% of sales"? If not, you may need to define some sort of scoring criteria.

Comment: @nrussell Yes, I think a criteria such as ">= 50% of sales" would also work for my problem. Would I be able to show what % of sales the function actually includes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[order(Store, Dist), 
   .(Dist, Sales = cumsum(Sales), Pct = cumsum(Sales) / sum(Sales)),
   by = "Store"][Pct >= 0.5, .SD[1,], by = "Store"]
#    Store Dist Sales       Pct
# 1:   One    5    18 0.7826087
# 2:   Two    9    20 0.7692308
```

---

- `setDT(df)` converts `df` into a `data.table`
- The `.(...)` expression selects `Dist`, and calculates the cumulative sales and respective cumulative percentage of sales, by `Store`
- `Pct >= 0.5` subsets this to only cases where cumulative sales exceeds the threshold, and `.SD[1,]` takes only the top row (i.e., the smallest value of `Dist`), by `Store`

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier if you rearrange your data in a certain format. My logic would be to first take `cumsum` by groups. Then merge sum of groups to the data. Finally i calculate percentage. Now You have got the data and you can subset in any way you want to get the first obs from the group.

```
df$cums=unlist(lapply(split(df$Sales, df$Store), cumsum), use.names = F)
zz=aggregate(df$Sales, by = list(df$Store), sum)
names(zz)=c('Store', 'TotSale')
df = merge(df, zz)
df$perc=df$cums/df$TotSale
```

sub-setting the data:

```
merge(aggregate(perc ~ Store,data=subset(df,perc>=0.5), min),df)
 Store      perc ID Dist Sales cums TotSale
1   One 0.7826087  2    5     8   18      23
2   Two 0.7692308  6    9     9   20      26
```